# Stopping an override function from the base function

Tags: c#, .net

I have a base void function called Update() which has to determine if the override Update() should be processed. As I understand a simple return; in the base function only stops the base function and not the override. So is there a way of doing that without writing anything more than base.Update() in the override?

```
protected virtual void Update()
{
    if (someArgument)
    {
        //Some code to stop the override from being processed
    }
}

protected override void Update()
{
    base.Update(); //It would be great if I didn't need to write anything more than this line to stop the override function
    //Some other code
}
```

Comment: Could you redesign it such that `Update` returns a `bool` to indicate whatever condition it is that occurs in the base method?

Comment: No, I'm afraid Update() has to be void as it is a function built into the engine.

Comment: In that case it seems like all you can really do is check the same condition after you run the base method.

Comment: You can't force a calling context to return gracefully, though you can forcefully terminate its execution by commit suicide (throw an exception (that it doesn't catch) or straight up kill the thread or entire process). Any reasonable way to do what you asked would rely on the caller checking something and then deciding to return. But what is this for? I feel like this weird problem could have been avoided in the first place.

Comment: Base classes do not know about their children. You can create a base class now and 10000 years later another developers may create a brand new class which inherits your base class. How is your base class suppose to stop the execution of a class which will be born 10000 years later?

(Anyway, I guess you may be using Unity game engine :D)

Comment: If all Update() does is check an argument, why can't u just separate that out to a new method in the base class called bool IsUpdateRequired() and then they can just call that to check?

Comment: The reason I'm using this kind of method is that a particular object has several classes which are inherited from the same parent class and all of them except one have to become inactive when a certain condition is met, the class that has to remain active needs other functions inherited from the parent so I would like it to have the same parent as others but ignore the Update() function. I thought I could do this by simply not calling base.Update() in the override function of the class that needs to ignore it.

Comment: To Public Wireless: I guess that could be a solution, however I wanted to achieve the desired result by using base.Update() as it seems natural use it with the override functions anyway (for me at least), but it looks like I will have to settle with your solution. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Thank you all for the help! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well if you have another method that is virtual you can deside if the overrided method should be called. Something like this. But you can't from the base class stop the execution of overridden methods.

```
class BaseClass
{
    protected void Update()
    {
        if(someArgument)
        {
            this.InnerUpdate();
        }
    }

    protected virtual void InnerUpdate()
    {
    }
}

class Foo : BaseClass
{
    protected override void InnerUpdate()
    {
        //Some other code
    }
}
```

Comment: Great idea! This solves the my issue perfectly! Thanks a lot :)